# how to make sure that Apache processes is chrooted?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze, chroot

I am using Apache 2 on Debian 6. I tried to make Apache by using following resource:
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-apache-env.en.html

how can i be sure that Apache is chrooted correctly?
if I delete /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (because i have copy of that in jail directory), would i expect that Apache still run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the config while the server is running doesn't show a thing because the config is only read on startup.

You can at least deduce that the server is running correctly in chroot, if you look where the logs are placed. If they are correctly placed, relatively to the chroot path, then your apache is most likely in a chroot.